# Error: more than one library with package name when trying to add google play services and add services in same project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Getting an error when trying to add

**Gradle: Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0'
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `play-services-*` dependencies must use the same version number - if you want to use `play-services-ads:8.4.0`, you have to also use `play-services-analytics:8.4.0`

Comment: getting another error Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>